# iOS. Архитектура страницы с несколькими непостоянными по высоте элементами

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Задача простая - страница поставщика для интернет магазина, состоит из изображения, наименования, краткого описания поставляемой продукции (View, постоянные по размерам), описания самого поставщика - может быть совершенно разной длины, соответственно высота View тоже варьируется и продуктов, которые поставщик поставляет. Продукты реализованы в виде `collectionview`, количество может быть разным. Если бы речь шла об Android я бы реализовал `RecyclerView`, в котором был бы хедер и продукты, в случае с iOS столкнулся с проблемой.

Собственно варианта было 2:

1) Пойти по аналогии с Android и разместить в корне `collectionView`, для которой создать два разных типа ячеек. Я уже делал это, но для ячеек, постоянных по высоте. В этом же случае необходимо задать автоматический размер для двух разных типов ячеек

2) Создать `scrollView`, в котороый уже поместить все view, а для описания поставщика ( `UITextView` ) и для продуктов ( `UICollectionView` ) отключить скролл, чтобы они растягивались по высоте.

В первом случае я не нашел толкового решения как сделать автоматический размер для разных типов ячеек, в лучшем случае я получал один столбец во весь экран, при этом `UITextView` был в одну строку (несмотря на то, что я по горизонтали и вертикали проставлял все Constrains).

Во втором, несмотря на то, что выглядит все до тошноты просто и по большей части отрисовывается, как мне хотелось - по какой то причине я не вижу `UIollectionView`. `DataSource` и `Delegate` указаны, после загрузки продуктов (они грузятся на старте страницы) я принудительно вызываю `reloadData()` и `setNeedsLayout()`. Constrains прописаны так, что `UICollectionView` совершенно точно находится под `UITextView`, однако результата нет.

Хотел бы спросить совета, как бы Вы реализовали такую сраницу? Если других вариантов нет, то прошу подсказать, что можно попробовать чтобы решить мою проблему для какого-нибудь из вариантов.

Comment: может проще отдебажить ваш пропавший UICollectionView?

Comment: Это было бы замечательно, но я не могу понять в чем дело. В первую очередь main.stroyboard - constraints указаны правильно, и в нужных местах. DataSource и Delegate указаны в storyboard и после отсутствия результата продублированы в код контроллера.Продукты я получаю всегда в количестве >1. Мной определены cellForItemAtIndexPath, numberOfItemsInSection (основан на количестве продуктов / 2), numberOfSectionsInCollectionView ( = 2). Что я мог забыть?